# No me pinta Google Map en la Web

Tags: javascript, api, map

Estoy intentando usar la `API` de Google Maps para que me pinte un mapa según las coordenadas que le paso, lo hago con el método `geolocation` de `HTML5`, pero no aparece nada en la web. He probado los parámetros que vienen por defecto en la documentación de Google y tampoco me funciona. El código es el siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Tu Aplicación del Tiempo</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>El Tiempo</h1>
    <h2 id="messageShow">Geolocalizando tú posición, espera un momento...</h2>

    <div id="map">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&callback=initMap"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</html>

//JavaScript

(function Prueba(){

if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getCoords, errorFound)
} else {
   alert("Upgrade your browser");
}

function errorFound(error) {
   alert("Error: " + error.code ); 
}

function getCoords(position) {
 var lat = position.coords.latitude;
 var lon = position.coords.longitude;

 console.log("Your position is: " + lat + "," + lon);

 $.getJSON({
    url: WEATHER_API_URL + "&lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon
  }, getCurrentWeather, initMap)
}

function initMap(){
var map;

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
   center: {lat: lat, lng: lon},
   zoom: 8
 });
}
})();
```

Hay una llamada `AJAX` a una `API` del tiempo que no tiene que ver con la pregunta, pero ahí si me funciona la geolocalización. La consola, me da el siguiente error: *InvalidValueError: initMap is not a function*

Espero me ayudéis con este error. Gracias.
Juan.

Comment: ¿Tienes un elemento con id "mapa" definido en el HTML?

Comment: Sí, lo tengo definido.

Comment: Sé que era una pregunta muy básica, pero nunca se sabe. Si abres la consola de JavaScript, ¿aparece algún error?

Comment: Sí, me dice que: initMap is not a function. Antes me daba otro error de la API de Maps, pero ya lo corregí.

Comment: ¿Entonces ya solucionaste el problema?

Comment: No, me sigue sin pintar nada. Probé en varios navegadores y nada. Añadí credenciales para trabajar en local con la API, eso fue lo que hice, pero sigue sin pintarme nada.

Comment: ¿Podrías crear un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Hola, Alavaro, modifiqué el código de la pregunta, no añado las llaves por seguridad.

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿Tu `function Prueba()` esta dentro de las tags `<script></script>`?

Comment: Está en un archivo aparte que lo llamo desde la etiqueta script del html que llama ./js/appjs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto es un problema con el ámbito (o *scope*) de las variables y de las funciones. Al hacer:

```
(function Prueba(){
    ....

    function initMap(){
    ....
    }

})();
```

la función `initMap` vive dentro de la función Prueba y no puede ser llamada fuera de ella (al menos no simplemente haciendo `initMap()` que es lo que se intentará con el *callback*).

La solución sería o bien quitar la parte de `Prueba()`:

```
//(function Prueba(){

if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getCoords,  
} else {
   alert("Upgrade your browser");
}

function errorFound(error) {
   alert("Error: " + error.code ); 
}

function getCoords(position) {
 var lat = position.coords.latitude;
 var lon = position.coords.longitude;

 console.log("Your position is: " + lat + "," + lon);

 $.getJSON({
    url: WEATHER_API_URL + "&lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon
  }, getCurrentWeather, initMap)
}

function initMap(){
var map;

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
   center: {lat: lat, lng: lon},
   zoom: 8
 });
}
//})();
```

o bien si por cualquier motivo necesitas que ese código se ejecute de esa manera, al menos mueve `initMap` fuera:

```
(function Prueba(){

if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getCoords, errorFound)
} else {
   alert("Upgrade your browser");
}

function errorFound(error) {
   alert("Error: " + error.code ); 
}

function getCoords(position) {
 var lat = position.coords.latitude;
 var lon = position.coords.longitude;

 console.log("Your position is: " + lat + "," + lon);

 $.getJSON({
    url: WEATHER_API_URL + "&lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon
  }, getCurrentWeather, initMap)
}


})();

function initMap(){
var map;

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
   center: {lat: lat, lng: lon},
   zoom: 8
 });
}
```

---

Actualización a partir del comentario- "*Bien, pero si lo hago así me da el error de que: lat, y lon no están definidas. En ambos casos*".

Eso es cuestión del ámbito de las variables y de cómo se llama a `initMap`. Ahora mismo las variables `lat` y  `lon` se definen de manera local en `getCoords` y no están disponibles fuera de ella, si quieres usarlas en otra función deberás hacerlas globales o pasarlas a las otras funciones. Además, tienes puesto que se llame a `initMap` cuando se cargue la API de Google Maps (con el `callback`) y también que se llame cuando se cargue el JSON en `getCoords`; incluso si estuviesen como globales, podría darse el caso de que el `callback` se llamara antes y siguieran sin estar definidas.

Cambia app.js a esto:

```
var lat, lon;

function getCoordinates() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getCoords, errorFound)
    } else {
       alert("Upgrade your browser");
    }
}

function errorFound(error) {
   alert("Error: " + error.code ); 
}

function getCoords(position) {
 lat = position.coords.latitude;
 lon = position.coords.longitude;

 console.log("Your position is: " + lat + "," + lon);

 $.getJSON({
    url: "map.php" + "?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon
  }, getCurrentWeather, initMap);

  initMap();
}

function initMap(){
   var map;
   console.log(lat + "," + lon);
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
     center: {lat: lat, lng: lon},
     zoom: 8
   });
}
```

y tengo este HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>El Tiempo</h1>
    <h2 id="messageShow">Geolocalizando tú posición, espera un momento...</h2>

    <div id="map" style="width:200px; height:200px">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=TU_API_KEY&callback=getCoordinates"></script>
```

Comment: Bien, pero si lo hago así me da el error de que: lat, y lon no están definidas. En ambos casos

Comment: Eso es cuestión del ámbito de las variables y de cómo se llama a `initMap`. Ahora mismo las variables `lat` y  `lon` se definen de manera local en `getCoords` y no están disponibles fuera de ella, si quieres usarlas en otra función deberás hacerlas globales o pasarlas a las otras funciones. Además, tienes puesto que se llame a `initMap` cuando se cargue la API de Google Maps (con el `callback`) y también que se llame cuando se cargue el JSON en `getCoords`; incluso si estuviesen como globales, podría darse el caso de que el `callback` se llamara antes y siguieran sin estar definidas.

Comment: @Juan prueba con el código que acabo de poner a ver si así te funciona (usa `lat` y `lon` como variables globales (algo no muy recomendado), y crea una función diferente (que es la que calcula las coordenadas y se llama con el `callback`). Prueba y dime si te funciona ahora

Comment: Hola @AlvaroMontoro, pues no, el console.log de la función initMap me devuelve: _undefined, undefined_ . ¿Podría hacerse algo como pasárselas por parámetro a la función initMap?. Como por ejemplo: initMap(lat, lon){}.

Comment: @juan Con el código de la última actualización (que no sé si es el mejor), me funciona y veo el mapa

Answer (score 1):

Que tal, trata de comprobar algunas cosas si crees que estas usando correctamente Maps.

> 1.- Si utilizas google chrome, este no te permite marcar puntos ya que necesitas un certificado para ello. Trata de usar otro navegador como
>   Firefox
>
> 2.- Trata siempre ir de menos a más en cuanto utilices alguna api.
>
> 3.- Revisa siempre lo que dice la consola, para saber mas detalles del problema

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

var map;
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 8
  });
}

    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```